# Firefox Quantum 57.0 64 bits High CPU

Tags: cpu

I recently updated Firefox and since then I've noticed high cpu usage. Peaks go to 80-90%, when normal surfing 30-40%.

Intel i5 1.6Ghz.
Dell Venue Pro 11
Ubuntu 17.10

Does anybody have experience similar issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. In Firefox go to: *Edit → Preferences → Privacy & Security → Cached Web Content*.
2. Check the box that says *Override automatic cache management*.
3. In *Limit cache to*, enter 16 MB. Close Firefox and restart it.

Works in Windows 10 and Mac OS.

Comment: Makes no difference to the problem on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 64bit with Firefox Quantum 62.0

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs in firefox throbber animation causing high CPU: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1419096

It's especially noticeable if you have tree style tabs installed, or have the tabs hidden for any reason: https://github.com/piroor/treestyletab/issues/1384

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution suggested by [@MkllSUMO](https://twitter.com/MkllSUMO) is to limit the content processes to 1 or 2. This solution worked immediately, there was no heating or CPU usage observed later.

```
-> about:preferences 
-> Performance 
-> Uncheck "Use recommended performance settings" 
-> Content Process Limit=2
```

This is how it looks like:
[image]